# C# equivalent HGlobal Pascal

Tags: c#, delphi

I'm converting the pascal interface into C#. What is the C# equivalent of the `HGlobal` data type?

```
type
  SomeFunction= function(var global : HGlobal) : integer; cdecl;
```

How would `SomeFunction` be declared in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the C# equivalent of the `HGlobal` data type?

The equivalent type is `IntPtr`.

> How would `SomeFunction` be declared in C#?

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int SomeFunction(ref IntPtr global);
```